# Cakepdf generating PDF View

Tags: cakephp, pdf

I have a problem with Cakepdf. I can generate .pdfs to my server, but can´t view them in my browser.

```
$CakePdf = new \CakePdf\Pdf\CakePdf();
$CakePdf->template('view', 'default');
$CakePdf->viewVars($this->viewVars);
// Get the PDF string returned
$pdf = $CakePdf->output();
echo $pdf;
```

Just gives me cryptic code like

```
%PDF-1.3 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R >> endobj 2 0 obj << /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Kids [6 0 R 14 0 R ] /Count 2 /Resources << /ProcSet 4 0 R /Font << /F1 8 0 R /F2 9 0 R >> /XObject << /I1 12 0 R /I2 13 0 R /I3 18 0 R /I4 19 0 R >> >> /MediaBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890] >> endobj 4 0 obj [/PDF /Text /ImageC ] endobj 5 0 obj << /Creator (DOMPDF) /CreationDate (D:20160208165451+00'00') /ModDate (D:20160208165451+00'00') >> endobj 6 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /Annots [ 10 0 R ] /Contents 7 0 R >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 819 >> stream x�}Uˎ�8��+������`O�d$H�<��,�@K�M�5|L�|}���� �-QbwUuus�眶�����HuÚ��ڪc5/�8����t<���g9�Ɂ��p�A�Eԁ��ncx�����M�������"���HEnW]��k�.�Z�;~�������(}xo�4�& V[G^F�=�v�� C��Ġ&�{5^Hj}�ɝ���6� ����rp��U��bUQd�h䊞�u��iP�є� ڀe�'��T��'/��B��K'<@J#�Z94e�ʮLh V�u��%�B�rD\�.Q2�{���0��K3A&hv�rO2*o��О�b��Y5f�k*�`i�2�e�$AͪX׫�=��|'c5ʨR�Z�:QWg�y�s��ҭZ$2Y�,jM}װ��KhJVWUM*I'��W`�2_o����8���>JzPA��R�QR�er2(�»9(]ɪ�Y�)rN�!�����h)��)�bNz�:� I�:Igi� dv�����t_�`�'�C�����JX�c{{{���:�qK�m>�O�5Ku��6a�X%�?f�2V 2n �$� kڸ�o��y����_�Y� endstream endobj xref 0 20 0000000000 65535 f 0000000009 00000 n 0000000074 00000 n 0000000120 00000 n 0000000351 00000 n 0000000388 00000 n 0000000502 00000 n 0000000584 00000 n 0000001475 00000 n 0000001587 00000 n 0000001694 00000 n 0000001821 00000 n 0000001895 00000 n 0000002860 00000 n 0000003940 00000 n 0000004024 00000 n 0000004307 00000 n 0000004434 00000 n 0000004508 00000 n 0000005473 00000 n trailer << /Size 20 /Root 1 0 R /Info 5 0 R >> startxref 6553 %%EOF
```

I have my default.ctp in Layout/pdf/default.ctp and my view in my controller. Simply won´t create an pdf online. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use the plugin as shown in the docs?

Comment: Well this didn´t help me much. I did everything like in the docs, but there is no real using. What they need is a technical editor or smth. I am not the first one having trouble with the docs...

Comment: Your problem is very likely related to encoding. make sure you set all your encoding stuff up correctly.

Comment: What rendering engine are you using? @ndm it is being used as documented :)

Comment: @Dakota Not really, the docs state to use the Pdf view to render documents for the browser. What the OP is doing, is just generating the PDF source, so without sending proper headers such an output is to be expected, at least after the more or less readable PDF header information. Would be helpful to know what exactly "_code like_" means, ie whether the complete output looks like that (no readable PDF header).

Comment: `Configure::write('CakePdf', ['download' => false]);` try this

Comment: I am using dompdf. And this is my output (code like ^^)

http://txs.io/tKQb

My encoding is set in app.php - 'encoding' => 'UTF-8'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is just regular PDF source content, and the fact that you are seeing it, instead of the browser recognizing it as a PDF document, is because you aren't sending a proper `Content-Type` header.

What I ment with "*use the plugin as shown in the docs*" in my comment, is the method that does that for you automatically, that is using the PDF view + Request Handler variant.

**[Readme > Render as PDF (including forced download) in the browser with PdfView](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf#1-render-as-pdf-including-forced-download-in-the-browser-with-pdfview)**
(also check **https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf/issues/147**)

If you don't do that, then you need to handle that on your own. In a controller action for example, you'd use the response object to set the body content and the required type/header, like

```
// ...
$pdf = $CakePdf->output();

$this->response->body($pdf);
$this->response->type('pdf');
return $this->response;
```

See also **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects > Response](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#response)**

Answer (score 0):

Here a short pdf preview example for CakePhp 4.3 with CakePdf 4.1 which works for me:

Invoice Controller:

```
public function pdfPreview() {
        $invoice = $this->Invoices->get(1);

        $CakePdf = new CakePdf();
        $CakePdf->template('view','invoiceLayout');
        $CakePdf->viewVars(['invoice' => $invoice]);
        $pdf = $CakePdf->output();

        //Or write it into a file if you want to
        //$CakePdf->write(APP . 'files' . DS . 'invoice.pdf');

        $this->response = $this->response->withType('pdf');
        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('pdfPreview');
        $this->set(['pdf' => $pdf]);
}
```

Layout "invoiceLayout":

Here belongt your Html design for your invoice pdf

```
<?= $this->fetch('content') ?>
```

Template "view"

Here belongs the content, which should be loaded into "invoiceLayout"
For example products

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo $product
}
```

Layout "pdfPreview":

```
<?php
echo $pdf;
?>
```

Hope this might help others.